# Spring data jpa insertion on partition table taking more time comparing to non partition table

Tags: spring-data-jpa, yugabytedb

We need some help on the below use case.
We are inserting data in Yugabyte DB using Spring Data JPA (YSQL).
We have observed a significant time difference on the partitioned table during INSERT DML.
Application is taking approx. 6 to 10 times more time during data logging in the partitioned
table.
We did some exercise with the JDBC connection and this time no much time difference was observed.
i.e. Application is taking almost the same time for a partitioned and non-partitioned table.
Base infrastructure is the same both times.

Comment: You need to increase logging to maximum levels in Spring to look what queries/transactions are being sent underneath to the db compared your JDBC example. 

Another way would be to set https://docs.yugabyte.com/latest/reference/configuration/yb-tserver/#ysql-log-statement to all and see the logs on yb-tserver on each case.

Comment: Thank you team for the response, will try above mentioned configurations and update the results